# Force Download Audio File in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm finishing up this website http://showtimesnow.com/bvofc/ and was testing it in Internet Explorer and found that the download button function is downloading the Audio file as a `.htm` file.
Below is my code of download function in javascript.

```
function Download(fileURL, fileName) {
    // for non-IE
    if (!window.ActiveXObject) {
        var save = document.createElement('a');
        save.href = fileURL;
        save.target = '_blank';
        save.download = fileName || 'unknown';

    try{
        var evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
            'view': window,
            'bubbles': true,
            'cancelable': false
        });
        save.dispatchEvent(evt);
        (window.URL || window.webkitURL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);
    } catch(e){
        // for IE == 11
        if(!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)){
            save.click();
        }
    }
    }
    // for IE < 11
    else if ( !! window.ActiveXObject && document.execCommand){
        var _window = window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
        _window.document.close();
        _window.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName || fileURL)
        _window.close();
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be the same file as provided in the URL​.

Comment: Which version of Internet Explorer has a problem? I see you have different code for different versions.

Comment: @ADyson both, I tried two different codes for `IE ==11` and `IE < 11` both are giving out the same result.

Comment: @ADyson I'm using two blocks for IE because of IE11 returns true for first `if` and gives an error in `try` so I added a condition block in `catch`